# running multiple anova tests in r

Tags: r, anova

I have seven groups that I want to run ANOVA test on to see if there is a significant difference among each other based on a trait. And I have about 600 traits.
I already calculated per group and per trait their mean, standard deviation, and variance. the seven groups have different sample sizes. How can I arrange my data so that I will be able to run them all in R?

Answer (score 1):

```
set.seed(2)

sampledata <- expand.grid(group = paste0("group", 1:7), trait = paste0("trait", 1:600), value = 1:5)
sampledata$value <- rnorm(nrow(sampledata))

sampledata.aov <- aov(value ~ group * trait, data = sampledata)
anova(sampledata.aov)

Analysis of Variance Table

Response: value
               Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value  Pr(>F)  
group           6     7.1  1.1784  1.1670 0.32072  
trait         599   658.0  1.0985  1.0878 0.07096 .
group:trait  3594  3613.0  1.0053  0.9955 0.56604  
Residuals   16800 16964.3  1.0098                  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

A warning though, even with random numbers, you're more likely than not to have a significant difference when you have this many traits at once.